# I am unable to add condition in resource based policy in lambda function using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I want to add source_account in lambda resource-based policy condition. So I am executing below terraform code.

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {
  # Retrieves information about the AWS account corresponding to the
  # access key being used to run Terraform, which we need to populate
  # the "source_account" on the permission resource.
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "example" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.example.arn}"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_account = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
  source_arn    = "${aws_s3_bucket.example.arn}"
}
```

after applying terraform changes and doing plan I am unable to get (this is desired but not getting for S3)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "lambda-8433be2d-00f7-48dc-9296-7c432662f91e",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:yyyyyyyyyyyy",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/lambda/lambda_handler:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried many ways I am not getting any clue.

afer doing terraform plan i am getting below output :

```
module.environment.aws_lambda_permission.xxxxxxxxxxxx: Creating...
  action:        "" => "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name: "" => "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:yyyyyyyyyyyyyy:function:xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  principal:     "" => "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn:    "" => "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  statement_id:  "" => "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
```

I am getting like this :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:yyyyyyyyyy:function:xxxxxxxxxx",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to add conditions using AWS CLI .
I am not using the root account. Someone please help me.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? The policies obtained are incorrect, do you get any errors?

Comment: I want to add ``` "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }, ```in  this policy

Comment: ```aws lambda add-permission --function-name xxxxxxxxxx --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket --principal s3.amazonaws.com --source-arn arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxx --source-account yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.``` if  I am executing this code  above condition is adding into resource based policy .how to added using terraform

Comment: Your  terraform plan output shows that you are not setting `source_account`. Are you sure you are looking at the correct terfform files?

Comment: Yes, I  am setting the correct terraform file . Don't know why source_account is not coming. As per terraform documentation, I can add source_account but really don't know what actually I am missing.

Comment: @Marcin any clue?

Comment: Sadly no. Your `aws_lambda_permission` seems correct. I don't know why it's skipping `source_account`.

Comment: @Marcin Mistake was from my end ....I did not update the file properly.

Comment: Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add source_account

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789123:function:mylambda"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_account = "123456789123"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
}
```

will create

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789123:function:mylambda",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": "123456789123"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```